# JSSOR multiple sliders - broken responsive

Tags: jssor

I have two JSSOR sliders working except the responsive part only works for one slider.

Even duplicating the responsive code does nothing. Anyone have any ideas?

```
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
        var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options);
        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end

    });
</script>
```

For all the code the website is http://garyedwardrotter.com and the portions with the sliders are in the photography section. Just the first two are setup right now and I have used the same exact code/slider setup for both.

Any help is very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
if (parentWidth)
    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));
```

with

```
if (parentWidth) {
    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));
    jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));
}
```

Comment: This was close. I figured out that you have to repeat the whole code: `function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider2.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));`

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was to repeat this code for the amount of sliders you will be using:

`function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider2.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));`